# How to support JS/Python scripting a C++ game engine?

Tags: c++, javascript, python, scripting

I'm currently writing an Entity/Component/System architecture game engine in C++, and I have the beginnings of a lua scripting system in place, which seems to be quite popular, but I feel Javascript or Python would be better.

My requirements are:

- Able to bind C++ function calls to the scripting language.
- Able to return data to the calling script.
- Able to support heavily templated libraries, such as glm (optional, but desirable)
- Must be lightweight.
- Must have open source license, or similar, with no restrictions on any potential commercial use.

How would I go about doing this, in a similar way to Lua?

Comment: Not sure why you think Lua is out of date.

Comment: Did you try to search for libraries already yourself? You will quickly find libraries like Duktape.

Comment: I did, but I guess I wasn't asking google the right questions. Thanks for the pointer though.